# With Spring Security are both encrypted and unencrypted passwords accepted in the same program?

Tags: spring, spring-security

SUMMARY:  In this Spring Security program I can login with (sam/abc125) and (neal/$ENCRYPTED_abc125).  Shouldn't the (sam/abc125) login fail?

DETAILS:
In the process of learning something new I copied a tutorial Spring Security project from [Websystique Spring Security 4 Hibernate Role Based Login Example](http://websystique.com/spring-security/spring-security-4-hibernate-role-based-login-example/) .  Works fine.  In particular there are login/password combos of (sam/abc125) and (kenny/abc127).  These logins work fine and the web page directs you to the proper place.

I wanted to add Bcrypt password encryption (from [Websystique Spring Security 4 Hibernate Password Encoder Bcrypt Example](http://websystique.com/spring-security/spring-security-4-password-encoder-bcrypt-example-with-hibernate/)) to this example -- adding it to the role based example seems preferable to adding role based stuff to the encrypted project version.  So I carefully copied the code from the encryption-enabled project to my role-based project.

I made slight adjustments to some JSP pages -- missing some DIVs needed for formatting.  I then added one new user record (neal/$ENCRYPTED_abc125).  The $ENCRYPTED_abc125 is "abc125" properly encrypted with BCryptPasswordEncoder.  I checked the "quick encoder" program results with what the web page provided.

The web site is accepting the (sam/abc125) login, even though the password "abc125" is stored in the clear in the user table.  It is also accepting the (neal/$ENCRYPTED_abc125) login, even though the password $ENCRYPTED_abc125 is stored encrypted in the user table.  It also accepts (kenny/abc127).

Since all of the authentication is hidden within Spring Security I can't debug my way through it.  I'm left with expert knowledge for my question, which is:

**Is there something within Spring Security that detects that the user table has an unencrypted password and encrypts it before comparing it with the user-supplied password text?**

Note that the clear-text passwords predate the conversion to an encrypted storage and wouldn't be there for a live version.  My question here is in trying to figure if something is broken or if it is working as designed.

Here is the security configuration from the project.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("customUserDetailsService")
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    CustomSuccessHandler customSuccessHandler;


    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider()); 
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authenticationProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder psswordEncoder() {  
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      http.authorizeRequests()
        //.antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/", "/home").access("hasRole('USER')")
        .antMatchers("/admin/**", "/newuser").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
        .antMatchers("/db/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN') and hasRole('DBA')")
        //.and().formLogin().loginPage("/login")
        .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").successHandler(customSuccessHandler)
        .usernameParameter("ssoId").passwordParameter("password")
        .and().csrf()
        .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/Access_Denied");
    }

}
```

Comment: Your explanation is confusing do you have 2 records for neal? or a single one? Do you enter the encrypted password in the password box or the unencrypted? Also you either set the `userDetailsService` and add the `passwordEncoder` or set the `authenticationProvider` you don't do both.

Comment: I have only one (username/password) record each for neal, sam and kenny.  Only neal has an encrypted password.  In the login page I enter the plain text password in every case.  I will examine the userDetailsService/authenticationProvider issue at my next break period.  Thanks for the reply.

Comment: I saw the two uses and removed the one from configureGlobalSecurity().  When done I got the results I want, such as "login kenny/abc127 fails while login neal/encrypted_abc125 succeeds".  When I instead removed the one from authenticationProvider() I got a runtime error that the DaoAuthenticationProvider *needs* a user details service".  There is only one possible edit that fixes this.  M. Denium, If you want credit please post an answer that I can put a check mark at.